# How to dynamically add widgets to a layout after a button is clicked

Tags: python, pyqt5

Whenever i click the + button i want to add a new row just like the first one (  a new + button next to a lineEdit) and also print the text inside the respective lineEdit.

i managed to do it this way, but i dont understand how the program knows which button i'm clicking on to print the text next to it!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

count = 1
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(569, 176)
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(Form)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.lineEdit_1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_1.setObjectName("lineEdit_1")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_1)
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.pushButton_1)
        self.pushButton_print = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_print.setObjectName("pushButton_print")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.pushButton_print)
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_print.clicked.connect(self.appear)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("Form", "+"))
        self.pushButton_print.setText(_translate("Form", "print 4th"))

    def add(self):
        global count
        count+=1
        new_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+", Form)
        new_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        #new_btn.setObjectName(f"pushButton_{count}")
        #new_line.setObjectName(f"lineEdit_{count}")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(count, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, new_btn)
        self.formLayout.setWidget(count, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, new_line)
        new_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(new_line.text()))
        new_btn.clicked.connect(self.add)

    def appear(self):
        lineEdit = Form.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, f"lineEdit_4")
        print(lineEdit.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

also when i bind the new buttons to "self" like "self.new_button", it will only print the latest lineEdit and not the earlier ones.

Why is this happening? is there a better way of doing what i want to do?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. Can you tell me what exactly you want? Can you also tell me if you want your button to display all your linedit text, or, do you want to have a button beside the lineedit that displays the corresponding lineedit text?

Comment: let me put it this way. Running my code you will see that when i click on the + button a new row is added. and it does not matther which + button i click on, every time a new lineEdit along with a new push button is created. now besides creating a new row, clicking + also prints the text inside the lineEdit next to it. What i dont understand is that how the program knows which push Button i'm clicking on and which lineEdit to print (since their variable name is all the same: new_btn and new_line). yes the buttons should print the corresponding lineEdit

Comment: My question is that how the program knows which lineEdit text it should print? they all have the same variable name!

Comment: @Heike but as new lineEdits are created how are the previous ones rememberd? Since the variable name now points to the latest one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the *scope* of local variables with instance attributes.

A lambda function always uses the *local* scope of the function in which it was created.
In your example, `new_line` is a reference created within the function `app`, *when it was created*. The result is that it will always refer to *that* line edit.

If you create an *instance attribute* (like `self.new_line`) then the reference is resolved on the object tree; in other words: find the "new_line" attribute of "`self`" (which is the `Ui_Form` instance, and the first argument of the function of any *instance method*). Since you're always overwriting that attribute everytime a new row is created, it will always refer to the *latest* line edit.

I've prepared a small example that could probably show the difference between the two aspects. The text field will show the result of the click: the *actual* clicked row (which is `row` in the *scope* of the `add` function) and the instance attribute *set* for that row, which is overwritten everytime a new row is created.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class ScopeTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.row = 0

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.logView = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(readOnly=True, minimumHeight=200)
        layout.addWidget(self.logView)
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add row')
        layout.addWidget(self.addButton)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame(frameShape=QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine))

        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add)

    def add(self):
        self.row += 1
        # note that the following line is important!
        # "row" is a *local* variable! "self.row" is an *instance attribute*!
        row = self.row
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Row {}'.format(self.row))
        self.layout().addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.log(row, self.row))

    def log(self, clickedRow, scopeRow):
        self.logView.appendPlainText('Clicked: {}, Scope: {}'.format(
            clickedRow, scopeRow))
        self.logView.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
            self.logView.verticalScrollBar().maximum())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = ScopeTest()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Some further suggestions:

- do some research on classes and instances, and how their *methods* and *attributes* work;
- search about the difference between `lambda` and `functool.partial`: they behave similarly (since they both return a reference to a function) but they evaluate their arguments differently; there are situations for which you might need one or the other;
- whenever objects are dynamically created, creating instance attributes for them is almost pointless since those attributes will always refer to the *last* created objects; unless you *really* need to know and refer to that last object, you should not create (nor overwrite) such attributes;
- files generated by `pyuic` should never, **NEVER** be modified (nor you should try to mimic their behavior); there are lots of reasons for which that is considered a bad practice, and since they're not on topic I'll just leave you with a "don't do that unless you **really** know what you're doing" (which usually leads to: "if you know what you're doing, you don't edit them"); read more about the correct uses of those files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html); luckily, the latest PyQt versions added a more verbose warning about that, and that warning should *never* be underestimated;
- `findChild` (and `findChildren`) should be used only for widgets internally created by Qt (such as the navigation buttons of a QCalendarWidget); using pyuic files (or `uic` module functions) automatically generates attributes for all widgets; if you have a widget named `lineEdit_4` in Designer and you created the GUI from the `.ui` file or using pyuic, you can already access that widget using `self.lineEdit_4`;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that the instrance attribute ```self.row``` is overriden everytime. You said "In your example, new_line is a reference created within the function app, when it was created. The result is that it will always refer to that line edit." . We create a new lineEdit and name it's variable ```new_line```, it's confusing me how the program can distinguish between lineEdits despite the fact that they all have the same variable name.

Comment: Also , let's say we have a button that on click shows the result if the 4th button if exists. How do we reference that 4th?

Comment: @Sherafati 1. Everytime `app` is called, a new `new_line` variable is created that is valid only for *that call* and references that line edit in that "scope". The fact that you always use the same name is influential; I suggest you to do some research about "variable scope". 2. I don't understand what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: let's say i click the "add row button 4 times". 4 new buttons will be added. Clicking each button prints information about that button ("Clicked: Scope:"). New let's say we have a button next to the "add row button" which prints the information of the 4th button(if it is added already) just as if we clicked on the 4th button itself. How can we do that? Or even simply print the text of that 4th pushbutton

Comment: @Sherafati then create an empty list in the `__init__` and add the widgets to that list everytime you create them, then if you want to access the fourth, just use that index, for example: `fourth_button = self.widgetList[3]`

Comment: should i append ```button``` (variable name) each time in your code? And you said i shouldn'be using ```findChild```

Comment: @Sherafati yes, just append the `button` (if you're interested in that), which is a reference to the QPushButton. I don't understand the last part of your comment: yes, you should not use findChild, so why are you asking it?

Comment: because we could easliy find the button we want using it's object name and ```findChild``` method. See the ```appear``` method in my code.

Comment: @Sherafati as said, findChild should only be used when the object is created by pyqt *internally*, using it for this is highly discouraged and pointless: just create a list to which you'll add the objects, and then use the index to access them.